# Can I increment an iterator by just adding a number?

Tags: c++, iterator

Can I do normal computations with iterators, i.e. just increment it by adding a number?

As an example, if I want to remove the element `vec[3]`, can I just do this:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
      vec.push_back(i);
}
vec.erase(vec.begin() + 3); // removes vec[3] element
```

It works for me (g++), but I'm not sure if it is *guaranteed* to work.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It works if the iterator is a random access iterator, which vector's iterators are (see [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator)). The STL function [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) can be used to advance a generic iterator, but since it doesn't return the iterator, I tend use + if available because it looks cleaner.

**C++11 note**

Now there is [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) and [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev), which *do* return the iterator, so if you are working in template land you can use them to advance a generic iterator and still have clean code.

Comment: Correct; added some documentation links that list which functions should be available to which types of iterators.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The + operator means "in one step, jump this far ahead" which a list iterator cannot do. Forward non-random-access iterators (like list iterators) support only support the increment (++) operator to advance one element at a time. As Todd said, you can use std::advance, which invokes the ++ operator repeatedly, to succinctly express the idea of moving a non-random iterator forward by a number of steps.

Comment: Well, to be pedantic, it isn't guaranteed to work for bidirectional iterators like list, but I believe it isn't guaranteed to not work either; an implementation could add it.

Comment: @TylerMcHenry: I believe that `std::advance` exploits `+` for random access iterators (i.e. it doesn't always invoke `++` repeatedly). The [`std::advance` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) seems to agree.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the compilation error when using + with a std::list iterator is a *benefit* over std::advance in some situations. If you were advancing an arbitrary number of places in a vector (not just one place as here) and need to do it in constant time, then someone changes the container to a list, this might be an error you want to catch. Better to catch it at compilation time than when you notice the bad performance later (maybe on production!). Also, using + rather than std::advance documents the expectation that it's a constant-time operation.

Comment: A point to note regarding std::advance and std::next.  The std::advances takes an iterator by reference, so it will modify the iterator that you pass in.  The std::next don't modify the input variable but will return the updated iterator.  Whether you wish to modify your original iterator will influence which one to use.

Answer (score 5):

A subtle point is that the `operator+` takes a `Distance`; i.e., a signed integer. If you increment the iterator by an unsigned, you may lose precision and run into a surprise. For example on a 64 bit system,

```
std::size_t n = (1 << 64) - 2;
std::vector<double> vec(1 << 64);
std::vector<double> slice(vec.begin() + n, vec.end());
```

leads to implementation-defined behavior. With `g++` or `clang`, you can ask the compiler to warn you about such undesired conversions with the warning flag `-Wsign-conversion` that is not part of the canonical `-Wall` or `-Wextra`.

A work-around is to work on the pointer directly

```
std::vector<double> slice(vec.data() + n, vec.data() + vec.size());
```

It's not pretty but correct. In some occasions, you need to construct the iterator manually, for example

```
std::vector<double>::iterator fromHere{vec.data() + n};
vec.erase(fromHere, vec.end());
```

Comment: Is there any documentation on the constructors available for std::vector::iterator?

Comment: The example here involves implicit conversion of the value of `n` from unsigned (size_t) to signed (Distance) type. This leads to **implementation-defined** behavior when the value of `n` is too large to be represented by `Distance` data type. _It will never lead to undefined behavior_.

Comment: I know the differences are subtle. On https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior, I found a citation of the standard that `An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow.`. I thought it would fall into that category. If it doesn't, can @ghd provide a statement from the C++ standard that it is implementation-defined?

Comment: In the example code snippet above, where is the possibility of integer overflow? The conversion of unsigned to signed is _not considered as overflow_ if the unsigned value cannot be represented as signed value. As per the C++17 working draft standard (N4659) **7.8**: _If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type;
otherwise, the value is implementation-defined._ Only [overflow in signed arithmetic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows) can result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Updated the answer to use _implementation-defined_ , thanks @ghd 
A related note is https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es106-dont-try-to-avoid-negative-values-by-using-unsigned

Answer (score 2):

It works with random access iterators. In general you may want to look at [std::advance](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/advance/) which is more generic. Just be sure to understand performance implications of using this function template.

Answer (score 1):

Number arithmetic is possible only with random access iterators such as those in std::vector and std::deque.

```
    std::vector<int>list={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    auto last_v=*(list.end()-1);
    auto third_last_v=*(list.end()-3);
    std::cout<<"Last & 3rd last entry for vector:"<<last_v<<","<<third_last_v<<std::endl;
```

will output 8 and 6, however for std::map, std::multimap, std::set, std::multiset having bidirectional iterator

```
    std::map<int,std::string> map_={{1,"one"},{2,"two"},{3,"three"}};
    auto last_mp=*(map_.end()-1);
    auto third_last_mp=*(map_.end()-3);
    std::cout<<"Last & 3rd last entry for map:("<<last_mp.first<<","<<last_mp.second<<") and ("<<third_last_mp.first<<","<<third_last_mp.second<<")"<<std::endl;
```

will result in
`error: no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘std::map, int>::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator, int> >}’ and ‘int’)`

For bidirectional iterator std::next(),std::prev or std::advance() works

```
    std::map<int,std::string> map_={{1,"one"},{2,"two"},{3,"three"}};
    auto last_mp=*std::prev(map_.end(),1);
    auto third_last_mp=*std::prev(map_.end(),3);
    std::cout<<"Last & 3rd last entry for map:("<<last_mp.first<<","<<last_mp.second<<") and ("<<third_last_mp.first<<","<<third_last_mp.second<<")"<<std::endl;
```

will output (3,three) and (1,one). On a similar note std::unordered_map has a forward iterator, so here std::next() makes sense to use.