# How to navigate through a vector using iterators? (C++)

Tags: c++, iterator, vector

The goal is to access the "nth" element of a vector of strings instead of the [] operator or the "at" method. From what I understand, iterators can be used to navigate through containers, but I've never used iterators before, and what I'm reading is confusing.

If anyone could give me some information on how to achieve this, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Aren't vectors exclusive to the STL of C++? I will edit it regardless

Comment: kevin: vector is a generic term which could be used by any language, particularly math-related ones like Mathematica or Matlab.

Comment: @michael, yeah haha I edited it after gabe's comment.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You need to make use of the [`begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) and [`end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end) method of the [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) class, which return the iterator referring to the first and the last element respectively.

```
using namespace std;  

vector<string> myvector;  // a vector of stings.


// push some strings in the vector.
myvector.push_back("a");
myvector.push_back("b");
myvector.push_back("c");
myvector.push_back("d");


vector<string>::iterator it;  // declare an iterator to a vector of strings
int n = 3;  // nth element to be found.
int i = 0;  // counter.

// now start at from the beginning
// and keep iterating over the element till you find
// nth element...or reach the end of vector.
for(it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end(); it++,i++ )    {
    // found nth element..print and break.
    if(i == n) {
        cout<< *it << endl;  // prints d.
        break;
    }
}

// other easier ways of doing the same.
// using operator[]
cout<<myvector[n]<<endl;  // prints d.

// using the at method
cout << myvector.at(n) << endl;  // prints d.
```

Comment: This misses the fact that `std::vector` has random access iterators.

Comment: Regardless of whether you know the iterator type is random-access or not, the "best" way to move an iterator forward n spaces is not to write your own loop, but to call `std::advance(it, n)`. It's defined to do exactly what you want, and it will automatically use `it + n` if the iterator is tagged as random-access, or do the loop if it has to.

Answer (score 102):

In C++-11 you can do:

```
std::vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (auto i : v)
{
   // access by value, the type of i is int
   std::cout << i << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

See here for variations: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: WHY DOES THIS HAVE ZERO LIKES?! <3

Comment: @jperl Posted 8 years late. Will take the next 8 years to get enough upvotes :)

Comment: @jperl, well the answer is off-topic. Although this loop feature is nice, it doesn't help you to know when you're at the nth element, which is the OP's question. Also, any answer that requires O(n) time complexity, such as this one, is very bad. Accessing the nth element of a vector should always be O(1).

Comment: @lashgar I tried this with array but failed. Does it work for array?

Comment: @eras'q, tried with gcc `7.5.0` on Ubuntu 18.04 and works for array the same way.

Comment: The name of the variable in the loop is misleading. Usually, `i` means index, in context `for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++)` but here you use a range-based for loop, which instead of index, gives you the element of the container you loop over. So the readable way is: `for (auto elem : v) {}`

Answer (score 70):

Typically, iterators are used to access elements of a container in linear fashion; however, with "random access iterators", it is possible to access any element in the same fashion as `operator[]`.

To **access arbitrary elements in a vector** `vec`, you can use the following:

```
vec.begin()                  // 1st
vec.begin()+1                // 2nd
// ...
vec.begin()+(i-1)            // ith
// ...
vec.begin()+(vec.size()-1)   // last
```

The following is an example of a **typical access pattern** (earlier versions of C++):

```
int sum = 0;
using Iter = std::vector<int>::const_iterator;
for (Iter it = vec.begin(); it!=vec.end(); ++it) {
    sum += *it;
}
```

The advantage of using iterator is that you can apply the **same pattern with other containers**:

```
sum = 0;
for (Iter it = lst.begin(); it!=lst.end(); ++it) {
    sum += *it;
}
```

For this reason, it is really easy to create template code that will work the same **regardless of the container type**.
Another advantage of iterators is that it doesn't assume the data is resident in memory; for example, one could create a forward iterator that can read data from an input stream, or that simply generates data on the fly (e.g. a range or random number generator).

Another option using `std::for_each` and lambdas:

```
sum = 0;
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&sum](int i) { sum += i; });
```

Since C++11 you can use `auto` to avoid specifying a very long, complicated type name of the iterator as seen before (or even more complex):

```
sum = 0;
for (auto it = vec.begin(); it!=vec.end(); ++it) {
    sum += *it;
}
```

And, in addition, there is a simpler for-each variant:

```
sum = 0;
for (auto value : vec) {
    sum += value;
}
```

And finally there is also `std::accumulate` where you have to be careful whether you are adding integer or floating point numbers.

Comment: Couldn't `vec.begin()+(vec.size()-1)` be out of standard because vec.size() is an unsigned long?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54803850/11200005

Answer (score 24):

Vector's iterators are random access iterators which means they look and feel like plain pointers.

You can access the nth element by adding n to the iterator returned from the container's `begin()` method, or you can use operator `[]`.

```
std::vector<int> vec(10);
std::vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin();

int sixth = *(it + 5);
int third = *(2 + it);
int second = it[1];
```

Alternatively you can use the [advance](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/advance/) function which works with all kinds of iterators. (You'd have to consider whether you really want to perform "random access" with non-random-access iterators, since that might be an expensive thing to do.)

```
std::vector<int> vec(10);
std::vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin();

std::advance(it, 5);
int sixth = *it;
```

Comment: You can use `advance` for random-access iterators too, or iterators of unknown category, since it is guaranteed to operate in constant time in that case. This is why user-defined iterators should be correctly tagged.

Comment: Indeed, but `advance` is really annoying to use (because of the out parameter usage) if you know you are dealing with random access iterators. Would only recommend in generic code, and if not used a lot (if the algorithm doesn't support non-random-access iterators well, so be it - for example, `std::sort` *could* sort a `std::list` but it doesn't because it would be ridiculously inefficient).

Comment: Sure, the classic example would be if your algorithm only actually *needs* an InputIterator, but for whatever reason it sometimes skips ahead, so you want it to be more efficient if the iterator does have random access. It's not worth restricting your algorithm to random access only by using `operator+`. But the question was explicitly about vector, so there's nothing wrong with the first part of your answer. I just thought the second part might imply "you can't use advance with random access iterators, even if you want to" to someone who has never seen `advance` before.

Comment: OK, reworded that bit and gave the example with a vector.

Comment: second line, `Vector` should be lower case

Comment: The first sentence is crucial, IMHO. I used to find STL iterators awkward, cryptic and unnatural to use until I realized they are like pointers - that was "eureka" moment for me.

Comment: wow, I didn't know `it[n]` is also possible! Where can I find the reference for that? I only found the operator[] for std::vector itself, not for its iterator, in cppreference.com.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of accessing the `ith` index of a `std::vector` using an `std::iterator` within a loop which does not require incrementing two iterators.

```
std::vector<std::string> strs = {"sigma" "alpha", "beta", "rho", "nova"};
int nth = 2;
std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;
for(it = strs.begin(); it != strs.end(); it++) {
    int ith = it - strs.begin();
    if(ith == nth) {
        printf("Iterator within  a for-loop: strs[%d] = %s\n", ith, (*it).c_str());
    }
}
```

Without a for-loop

```
it = strs.begin() + nth;
printf("Iterator without a for-loop: strs[%d] = %s\n", nth, (*it).c_str());
```

and using `at` method:

```
printf("Using at position: strs[%d] = %s\n", nth, strs.at(nth).c_str());
```