# Inserting into a specific part of a string using iterators? (C++)

Tags: c++, iterator

```
string str = "one three";
string::iterator it;
string add = "two ";
```

Lets say I want to add: "two " right after the space in "one".
the space would be str[3] correct? so: in this case, n = 3;

```
for (it=str.begin(); it < str.end(); it++,i++) 
{
  if(i == n) 
  {                   
    // insert string add at current position          
    break;
  } // if at correct position
} // for
```

*it would allow me to access the character at str[3], but I don't know how I would add in the string from there. Any help is appreciated, thanks. If anything is confusing or unclear please let me know

Comment: This seems to be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395275/how-to-navigate-through-a-vector-using-iterators-c and the rather questionable piece of code in your accepted answer (you won't really ever use such a convoluted way to get to the nth iterator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [`insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/) method of the string class.

```
string str = "one three";
string add = "two ";
str.insert(4,add); // str is now "one two three"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::string::insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/). Either do

```
str.insert(n, add);
```

or use the following more generic version, which works for any container (not only `std::string`).

```
str.insert(str.begin() + n, add.begin(), add.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string::iterator it = str.begin() + 4;
str.insert(it, add.begin(), add.end());
```

Comment: Actually you'd want 4. `insert` inserts before the item given by iterator, not after. (You want to insert after the space, i.e before the next character after the space.)