# Modern way to iterate over a collection with pointers

Tags: c++

A use of pointers is the ability to iterate and update a collection, for example:

```cpp
char list[3]{'a', 'b', 'c'};

char *pointer{list};

pointer++;

*pointer = 'd';

std::cout << list[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << list[1] << std::endl;
std::cout << list[2] << std::endl;
```

Will result in

```
a
d
c
```

Great, but raw pointers and C-style arrays are deprecated in modern C++, in favour of smart pointers, like `std::unique_ptr` and smart containers, like `std::vector`.

I tried a bit, but with no result, for example:

```cpp
char list[3]{'a', 'b', 'c'};

std::unique_ptr<char> pointer{std::make_unique<char>(list[0])};

(*pointer)++;

*pointer = 'd';
```

Will still result in

```
a
b
c
```

What am I missing?

And is it a way to use with `std::vector`?

Comment: "Modern" way is not to iterate over pointers at all. But to do a range based for loop over a container containing instances of objects.

Comment: Have you noticed that you are incrementing the dereferenced value of your pointer, and attempting to set the value using the same dereference? Regardless, there are very few good reasons to pass around pointers to vectors.

Comment: `unique_ptr`s are for _owning_ pointers and `std::unique_ptr<char> pointer{std::make_unique<char>(list[0])};` doesn't create a pointer _to_ `list[0]` but allocates memory for a `char` and initializes it with the value of `list[0]` (it's a copy construction)

Comment: The purpose of `std::unique_ptr` is to manage a data resource. Therefore it doesn't make sense to use `std::unique_ptr` to manage an element in a list allocated on the stack (and owning the data).

Comment: You're assuming that `unique_ptr` is very similar to a pointer, but it is almost nothing like one.

Comment: You may be looking for iterators, which define operations that make them look somewhat like pointers, but they’re no longer considered “modern”. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395275/how-to-navigate-through-a-vector-using-iterators-c#2395311 With an interator you can `it++` and `*it` if that’s what you like to do.

Comment: *"Great, but raw pointers and C-style arrays are deprecated in modern C++, in favour of smart pointers, like `std::unique_ptr` and smart containers, like `std::vector`."* You misinterpreted what you've heard. It's doing ***dynamic allocations*** yourself and keeping the result stored in a raw pointer that's considered bad practice in many situations (see RAII). The first code snippet in the question is fine, whether you're evaluating it by pre C++11 standards or C++20 standards (, that is if you've got a valid reason for not using `list[1] = 'd';` instead of doing pointer shenanigans).

Comment: You're confusing concepts. Pointers *can* be used in several ways (e.g. iterate over a collection, as a handle to access an array), but are easy to misuse. `unique_ptr`s *manage* a pointer (and the object it points at) but are not used to iterate. Standard containers (`std::vector`, etc) manage a collection, and *iterators* are used to iterate over the collection - and a pointer *can* be used or viewed as a primitive/unsafe iterator.  "Modern" ways to iterate over a collection use iterators other than pointers OR range-based loops (which use iterators in some specified ways).

Answer (score 0):

Only ever user pointers to single objects. And you can't iterate over single objects. So as Pepijn says the modern way is not to do that at all.

For your case you can just use `std::array` like so:

```
std::array list{'a', 'b', 'c');

for (const auto &c : list) { std::cout << c << std::endl; }
```

For dynamic cases use `std::vector` or any of the other containers.

Answer (score 0):

Loop like this :

```
// #include <array> for fixed size arrays.
#include <vector> // arrays that can change at runtime, to avoid manually having to write new/delete (or std::make_unique)
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> characters{ 'a','b','c' };
    std::vector<std::string> strings{ "Hello", "World" };

    characters.push_back('d'); // add new items to the container

    // use const since loop shouldn't change content
    for (const char character : characters)
    {
        std::cout << character << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    // use reference to avoid copy of string in vector to string in loop
    for (const auto& string : strings)
    {
        std::cout << string << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```