# How to make a QStringList iterator start from a specific index

Tags: c++, qt, loops, iterator, qstring

I'm working on a QStringList where the program has a main iterator to go through each word. Now I want to implement a sub-iterator where I want the sub-iterator to start at a certain position.

Here is a simple visualization of my code:

```
for(QStringList::iterator pkg_header(inputline.begin()); pkg_header != inputline.end(); ++pkg_header){ 
   ...
   if(!QString::compare(*pkg_header,Computing)){
      for(QStringList::iterator pkg_section(pkg_header+1; pkg_section != pkg_header.end(); pkg_section++){
         ...
   }
}
```

In other words, I need help to make the sub-iterator start from `pkg_header+1` position instead of doing `pkg_header.begin()`.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next)?

Comment: This is simpler than you think. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033089/can-i-increment-an-iterator-by-just-adding-a-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you can just use `operator + (int)` with `QStringList` iterators (somebody correct me if I'm wrong):

```
for (QStringList::iterator pkg_section = pkg_header + 1;
     pkg_section != inputline.end(); 
     pkg_section ++) 
    ...
```

But even if not, you can always do:

```
QStringList::iterator pkg_section = pkg_header;
for (pkg_section ++; pkg_section != inputline.end(); pkg_section ++) 
    ...
```

Apologies if you can't do `+ 1`, I'm just not in a position to conveniently check for `QStringList` right now.

Also you seem to have some confusion about the termination condition for your loops. I am assuming you meant `inputline.end()`, as `pkg_header.end()` isn't valid... `pkg_header` is an `iterator`, it doesn't have an `end()`.