# Find maximum element from a vector for a given range

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have tried to use the max function but it needs a iterator and that are A.begin and A.end but for my program I want to find for a range say from i to x .I tried to read the docs but was unable to find the solution. Any help would be appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: vector provides random access iterators so you can easily convert index to iterator `items.begin() + i`

Comment: It would be better if you could provide some real code

Comment: That's the good thing about all the [standard algorithm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), they take a *range*. Iterators doesn't have to be just the beginning and end, it can be anything in between.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I increment an iterator by just adding a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033089/can-i-increment-an-iterator-by-just-adding-a-number)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not looking for max. But for [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

To use it:

```
std::vector<int> v;
// fill it
auto max_it = std::max_element(v.begin()+i, v.end());
```

And to check in the range [i,j):

```
auto max_it = std::max_element(v.begin()+i, v.begin()+j);
```

`max_it` here is an iterator, to get the number from it:

```
int max_number = *max_it;
```