# Count in substring - fix compiler warnings

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

The `count_occurences` code finds the number of occurrences of character `c` in the string between positions `start` (included) and `end` (excluded). E.g. the following code counts `,` in `,b,` (substring of `a,b,c` from `1` to `4`), which is `2`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

size_t count_occurences(const std::string& str, char c, size_t start, size_t end) {
    return std::count(str.begin() + start, str.begin() + end, c);
}

int main() {
    std::string str = "a,b,c";
    size_t start = 1, end = 4;
    std::cout << count_occurences(str, ',', start, end);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with `clang++ -Wconversion`, I get the following warnings:

```
a.cpp:5:12: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: '_Iter_diff_t<_String_const_iterator<_String_val<_Simple_types<char>>>>' (aka 'long long') to 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Wsign-conversion]
    5 |     return std::count(str.begin() + start, str.begin() + end, c);
      |     ~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
a.cpp:5:58: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long long') to 'difference_type' (aka 'long long') [-Wsign-conversion]
    5 |     return std::count(str.begin() + start, str.begin() + end, c);
      |                                                        ~ ^~~
a.cpp:5:37: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long long') to 'difference_type' (aka 'long long') [-Wsign-conversion]
    5 |     return std::count(str.begin() + start, str.begin() + end, c);
      |                                   ~ ^~~~~
```

What is the proper way to fix these warnings **without changing the signature of `count_occurences`**? I can of course use `static_cast` everywhere, but it's more about silencing the warning than fixing it.

(In the real code, `start` and `end` are fields, so the function only has 2 parameters.)

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Can I increment an iterator by just adding a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033089/can-i-increment-an-iterator-by-just-adding-a-number).

Comment: There isn't a way to silence the warning without modifying function signature or without a cast. GSL has `gsl::narrow` and `gsl::narrow_cast` to express the intent clearly (throw exception in the first one if it would overflow).

Comment: Do you hate `std::count(&str[start], &str[end], c);`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'fix' the warning.  The warning is valid.  Argument should be of type `std::iter_difference_t<char>` not `size_t`.  Conversion is implementation defined.

Comment: @TimRoberts, Not sure. I think it's better to not involve pointers when possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could silence these warnings individually for the function, but it's not worth the effort:

```cpp
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wconversion"
size_t count_occurences(const std::string& str, char c, size_t start, size_t end) {
    return std::count(str.begin() + start, str.begin() + end, c);
}
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Note that GCC would give you warnings about unrecognized pragmas, so you'd actually need a lot more than just this.
`_Pragma` could help you minimize this somewhat, but it's still much more complicated than just using `static_cast`:

```cpp
size_t count_occurences(const std::string& str, char c, size_t start, size_t end) {
    // strictly speaking, the right type is std::string::difference_type,
    // not ptrdiff_t
    return std::count(str.begin() + static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(start),
                      str.begin() + static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(end),
                      c);
}
```

This is still the most self-documenting solution.
It may not be a satisfying answer, but it is the right way.

The underlying problem is that iterators usually require a signed integer such as `ptrdiff_t` and you're doing math with an unsigned integer.
Your warning isn't a false positive, and `static_cast` would document that you're aware of these type difference and knowingly convert.

#### Alternative solutions in this specific case

@TimRoberts has also pointed out that you could write

```cpp
std::count(&str[start], &str[end], c);
```

This solution only works for contiguous containers, but it is more compact than `static_cast`.*

Yet another solution presents itself in C++17:

```cpp
size_t count_occurences(std::string_view str, char c) {
    return std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), c);
}
```

The user can simply call `count(my_view.substr(...), 'c')` if they want a specific start and end.